# Правильно ли реализован класс?

Tags: javascript, ооп, классы, инспекция-кода

Прохожу по одному учебнику практические задания, но там нет решения чтобы свериться, что-то мне подсказывает что я мог не правильно понять задание или не добавить какие-то нужные проверки возможно? Мне лично что-то кажется метод get не очень хорошо реализован. Не могли бы вы проверить и подсказать?

Само задание:
Класс Store в ООП в JavaScript
Давайте реализуем класс Store, который будет представлять собой оболочку над локальным хранилищем и позволит легко сохранять и изменят в нем хранящиеся структуры данных.

Давайте посмотрим, как мы будем работать с описанным классом. Для начала создадим его объект:

let store = new Store;
Теперь сохраним данные с заданным ключом:

store.set('key', {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
Получим эти данные по ключу:

let res = store.get('key');
console.log(res); // {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
Получим часть сохраненной структуры, указав несколько ключей через точку:

let res = store.get('key.a');
console.log(res); // 1
Получим другую часть по сложному ключу:

let res = store.get('key.b');
console.log(res); // 2

1. Реализуйте описанный класс.
2. Сделайте метод, который будет изменять данные по заданному ключу.
3. Сделайте метод, который будет удалять данные по заданному ключу.

Мой код:

```
class Store {
  set(key, value) {
    this.key = value;
  }
  get(key) {
    let obj = key.split('.')[0];
    let nested = key.split('.')[1];
    return this.obj[nested] ?? this.obj;
  }
  setData(key, value) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      this.key = value;  
    }
  }
  deleteData(key) {
    // this.key = {};
    delete this.key;
  }
}

let store1 = new Store;
store1.set('key', {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
store1.setData('key', 15);
store1.deleteData('key');
```

Answer (score -1):

Я нашел решение:

```
class Store {

    set(key, value) {
        value = JSON.stringify(value);
        localStorage.setItem(key, value);
    }

    get(key) {
        console.log( JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key)) );
    }
}

let store = new Store;

store.set('key', {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3});
store.get('key');
```

Остальное по аналогии.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]